# delete statement is taking to much time

Tags: sql-server

I am a fresher just joined IT sector. I am asked to tune SP which are taking more time.

I came accross a SP which is taking more time, found that a particular DELETE statement is taking more time.
Table consists of Billions of records, out of which few billions of records needs to be deleted whenever SP runs. Table is having clustered Index which includes the SHOT_DATE column. The statement is given below. Please give some suggestions.

```
DELETE FROM TBL_STUDENT WHERE SHOT_DATE <= @YEAR AND
    SHOT_DATE <> EOMONTH(SHOT_DATE)
```

Comment: Due to the use of `EOMONTH` on `SHOT_DATE`, this query isn't going to be SARGable, so it's only going to be as fast as a table scan.

Comment: @Keshav : Add INDEXING in table. only way to speed-up your query

Comment: `SHOT_DATE <= @YEAR` What is the data type for  `@YEAR` ?

Comment: An index isn't going to help @im_one, not with that function there. Do you use `EOMONTH` on that column a lot? Perhaps it would be better off as a persisted computed column.

Comment: @Larnu an index on `SHOT_DATE` can certainly help for the `<= @YEAR` predicate

Comment: But it won't help for `SHOT_DATE <> EOMONTH(SHOT_DATE)` @MartinSmith, that's the problem.

Comment: Yes I realise that but the statement that the index won't help at all and they will get a full table scan is false. If the table has 10 distinct years and they are doing this clean up on the oldest year it will still eliminate 90% of the scan

Answer (score 0):

Also some best practices

As the table has BILLIONS of rows, it's always best to delete in batches (small to large) to prevent blocking or log file growth

pseudo-code

```
DECLARE @startDate DATE @endDate DATE, @batchSize INT
SELECT @startDATE = Date1 --set them however you wish
SELECT @endDate = Date2


While there's data still --either use SELECT COUNT(1) OR WHILE EXIST (...)
    DELETE TOP(@batchSize) FROM TBL_STUDENT WHERE SHOT_DATE BETWEEN @Date1 AND @Date2

--Sometimes I add a WAITFOR to have a break between delete, so other sessions can use the table
```

Another code

```
DECLARE @Criteria DATETIME
    ,@RowCount INT

SELECT @Criteria = GETDATE() - 60
    ,@RowCount = 10000

WHILE @RowCount = 10000
BEGIN
    DELETE TOP (10000)
    FROM ExampleTable
    WHERE DateTimeCol < @Criteria

    SELECT @RowCount = @@ROWCOUNT
END
```

Comment: Rather than control the batch loop with `SELECT COUNT` or `EXISTS`, it would be better to use `DECLARE @RowsDeleted int = -1;`WHILE @RowsDeleted <> 0` and `SET @RowsDeleted = @@ROWCOUNT` after each `DELETE`.